# "Is not in camelCase" warning when props are individually generated from a unique object

Tags: vue.js, prop

I pass an object `configObject` as prop to my child component:

```
<custom-button v-bind="configObject" />
```

This object contains various properties which I define individually inside my child component in order to extract the corresponding values:

```
props: {
  button_id: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  is_external_link: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  display_button: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  ...
},
```

This works perfectly, but `Vue` complains that these props aren't in camelCase. Yet if I rename them camelCase-style (`button_id` -> `buttonId`), the data isn't passed anymore such that `buttonId` is empty for example.

How to resolve this dilemma?

EDIT: `configObject' looks like below.

```
{
  button_id: '123',
  text: 'blabla',
  link: 'https://google.com',
  is_external_link: true,
  image: 'https://cdn.image.jpg',
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accessing, from my child component, the prop object's properties directly - `configObject.property`, after retrieving it the regular way:

```
props: {
  configObject: {
    type: Object,
    default: null
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the syntax you use to pass props, but my approach would be like this:

```
<custom-button :config="configObject" />
```

```
props: {
  config: {
    type: Object,
    default: ()=>({...}) // give schema if you like.
  },
},
data() {
  return {
    ...this.config,
    otherKey: "other value",
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I understand completely though. Where, for example, does `button_id` become `buttonId` in this code?

Comment: In this code, you pass your current props in configObject and inject them into data thanks to the spread operator. So they are not individual props anymore. Which means prop rules can be applied to them. So you don't need buttonId.